# Is the Fisher-Information even continuous in a regular statistical model?

Tags: statistics, continuity, variance, parameter-estimation, fisher-information

> **Definition (Regular Model [1, p. 203]).**
> A standard [statistical model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_model) $\big( X, \mathcal F, (\mathbb P_{\vartheta})_{\vartheta \in \Theta}\big)$, where $\Theta \subset \mathbb R$ is an open interval, $X \ne \emptyset$, $\mathcal F$ is a [$\sigma$-algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-algebra) on $ X$ and $\mathbb P_{\vartheta}$ is a [probability measure](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_measure) on $( X, \mathcal F)$ for every $\vartheta \in \Theta$ such that there exists a measure $\mu_0$ with $\mathbb P_{\vartheta} \ll \mu_0$ ([absolute continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Absolute_continuity_of_measures)) for all $\vartheta \in \Theta$ is **regular**, if the *[likelihood function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function)* $$\rho \colon X \times \Theta \to \mathbb{R}, \qquad (x, \vartheta) \mapsto \frac{\text{d} \mathbb P_{\vartheta}}{\text{d} \mu_0}(x)$$ ([Radon-Nikodym derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem#Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_derivative)) is positive and continuously differentiable (almost everyhwere) with respect to $\vartheta$.

Then the [score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Score_(statistics))
$$
U_{\vartheta}(x)
:= \frac{\partial}{\partial \vartheta} \ln\big(\rho(x, \vartheta)\big)
= \frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial \vartheta} \rho(x, \vartheta)}{ \rho(x, \vartheta)}
$$
is well defined.

For a regular model, we also require that the [Fisher information of the model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information#Definition) $I(\vartheta) := \mathbb{V}_{\vartheta}[U_{\vartheta}]$, where $V_{\vartheta}$ is the [variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Definition) with respect to $\mathbb P_{\vartheta}$, is always an element of $(0, \infty)$ and that
\begin{equation}
\int_{ X} \frac{\partial}{\partial \vartheta} \rho(x, \vartheta) \, \text{d}{\mu_0(x)}
\overset{!}{=} \frac{\partial}{\partial \vartheta} \underbrace{\int_{ X} \rho(x, \vartheta) \, \text{d}{\mu_0(x)}}_{= 1}
= 0
\end{equation}
holds, where we require that the left side is well defined, that is, that $\frac{\partial}{\partial \vartheta} \rho(\cdot, \vartheta)$ is integrable with respect to $\mu_0$.

---

It is not difficult to show that $\mathbb{E}_{\vartheta}[U_{\vartheta}^2] = 0$ and thus that $I$ is lower continuous due to [Fatou's Lemma](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FatousLemma.html)).

#### My question: Is $I$ even continuous?

*Remark.*
The proof of the [Cramér-Rao inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound) one shows that if that the inequality is an equality, then $I$ is continuous, but the requirements of that theorem are, among others, that the [estimator is regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound#Regularity_conditions) and that the expected value of the estimator with respect to $\mathbb P_{\vartheta}$ is continuously differentiable with respect to $\vartheta$ with pointwise non-vanishing derivative.

[1](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function) *Georgii, Hans-Otto*, [**Stochastics. Introduction to probability and statistics. Translated by Marcel Ortgiese, Ellen Baake and the author.**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/9783110206760), de Gruyter Textbook. Berlin: de Gruyter (ISBN 978-3-11-019145-5/pbk; 978-3-11-020676-0/ebook). ix, 370 p. (2008). [ZBL1270.62005](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1270.62005).